# deleting resources during CDK deploy?

Tags: aws-cdk

How can I delete unused resources during a CDK deploy?  I'm creating a VPC with:

```
vpc = ec2.Vpc(self, id = "myTestVPC", max_azs = 3, 
              cidr = "10.120.0.0/16", 
              subnet_configuration = [ presentation_nc, logic_nc, data_nc ])
```

So I wind up with 9 subnets - 3 public and 6 private.  I want to use 1 routing table for the public subnets and 1 for the private.  I'm doing that by iterating over vpc.private_subnets and vpc.public_subnets, and associating the routing tables with ec2.CfnSubnetRouteTableAssociation.  That part works.

Now I have 7 unused routing tables that I want to get rid of.  How can I do that?

Answer (score -1):

Set the removal policy to DESTROY and remove the stack from cloudformation or remove the code from cdk application.

```
vpc.applyRemovalPolicy(RemovalPolicy.DESTROY)
```

Comment: The question is not about removing the VPC or about removing the stack, it's about removing the auto-created routing tables.